# React Native preview Base64 encoded files

Tags: react-native, expo, base64, preview, quicklook

I am working on a mobile app in React Native. This app provides users with files witch they can download an share, as well as allow the user to upload their own files.

The files come in a Base64 format from the endpoints, and I want to allow the user to preview them. I initially tried using a library called `react-native-file-viewer`, as well as different iterations of this library. It did exactly as I want, but it isn't the best, as it doesn't seem to be up to date with the latest versions of `gradle`, and requires me to use `--legacy-peer-deps` when installing, and just causes difficulties when installing other packages.

For this reason, me and my senior decided it isn't the best package and we have since decided to remove it.

I haven't had any luck finding a more modern package, that can handle previews for Base64 encoded files.

I am looking for recommendations if anyone has experience dealing with this kind of thing.